# TextBox1.Text string on end of a link

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I wanted to make an application that checks if a link was blocked on steam.

I used the linkfilter page. (https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=)

I tried doing it like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Url = https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=(TextBox1.Text)
```

But I got two errors. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what are the errors you get? show some code too, unless we can't help you in any way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting your string values as actual strings?:

```
WebBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=" + TextBox1.Text);
```

or:

```
WebBrowser1.Url = new Uri(string.Format("https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url={0}", TextBox1.Text));
```

Comment: @MilkGames: What language are you using?  I guess I assumed C#.  The concept is the same in VB, though.  Treat strings as strings.

Comment: I tried removing the "@" but i got the Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Uri'. error.

Comment: @MilkGames: Well, the *type* of the property you're trying to set is important.  You were trying to set it to a string, so I assumed it was a string.  If it's a `Uri`, set it to a `Uri`.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.